# Use of 'the' after preposition for describing people's outfit

Tags: prepositions, articles

Which one is the correct answer and why? I don't know what the difference is between "in striped shirt" and "in **the** striped shirt":

> She is the woman in striped shirt.
>
> She is the woman in **the** striped shirt.
>
> She is the woman with striped shirt.

Comment: I would add 4. She is the woman with the striped shirt.

Comment: Not that it  matters in terms of article use, but why are you asking about *striped pants* when your example sentences talk about *striped shirts*?

Answer (score 1):

Normall, and certainly whenever you are talking about a particular person, you need an article.

When you are using this to identify the person, you could use *the* or *a*; but *the* I think is more common:

> Do see her? The woman in the/a striped shirt?

I can't find any difference in meaning between these.

When you are introducing a new specific person into the discourse, so you use *a* about the person, you also use *a* for the subsidiary description:

> Then a woman in a striped shirt stood up.

Comment: You would use the indefinite article *a* if you were identifying someone who shared that characteristic with other members of the group from which you were selecting.  It would be of little help to show you a picture of three hundred people and say. *Look for Bob.  He's **the** guy in **the** green shirt.*  That's very deterministic language.  Chances are there is more than one guy in a green shirt.  If I said, *Look for Bob.  He's **a** tall redhead wearing **a** green shirt,* I am telling you that you will have to select from a subset of tall, redheaded green shirters.

Answer (score 0):

English requires an article between the preposition and the noun. In rare cases it can  be implied. 
... woman in a / this / that / the (etc.) shirt. Each of these has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: does it mean grammatically they are all correct?

Comment: @user98713 Using an article is correct grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

> She is the woman in striped shirt. (incorrect)
>
> She is the woman in the striped shirt. (correct)
>
> She is the woman with striped shirt. (incorrect)

She is the woman in/with a striped shirt. (correct)